# JPanel Resize not happening

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, joptionpane, preferredsize

```
final JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,3));
 JPanel guiCenter = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,3));

 JPanel buttonConstrsint = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
             JButton getQuotesButton = new JButton("Get Quotes..");

              getQuotesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    JTable table = new JTable(generateRandomTableModel());
                     JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
                    guiCenter.add(pane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    //guiCenter.setVisible(true);
                    gui.add(guiCenter,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    gui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
                    gui.revalidate();
                    gui.repaint();
            }
        });

  buttonConstrsint.add(getQuotesButton);
  guiCenter.add(buttonConstrsint,BorderLayout.NORTH);

 // gui.add(labelFields,BorderLayout.NORTH);
  gui.add(guiCenter,BorderLayout.CENTER);

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
```

Can somebody help me why my gui panel can't resizable, when I load the table I'm expecting it to automatically expand.

Comment: Again, please put some effort into creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org), a small program that we can compile, run, modify, and hopefully help you correct.

Comment: Do you really need a JOptionPane here, why not just a dialog?

Comment: @user905374, why use a JDialog? Then you need to write all the listeners to handle the "Ok", "Close" buttons etc. JOptionPane does all this for you in one statement.

Comment: @camickr Ok good point, i'm used to JDialogs, I only use JOptionPane for quick prompts. I was not aware it can be used like this.

Comment: Did you really intend to add `pane` (the JScrollPane) to the BorderLayout.SOUTH position of `guiCenter`?  A component in an edge of a BorderLayout (as opposed to the center) will not stretch both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @camickr there is about add JComponent on runtime, but JOptionPane haven't pack(); then all handles required for resize this contianer are ...

Comment: It doesn't matter, where i add jpane, but I want to see once I add table under button, I want to see re-sized table, also how can i stretch the pane with mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I think you are trying to do:

Also pls have a look at how to use [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and how to use [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2, 3));

        JPanel buttonConstrsint = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        JButton getQuotesButton = new JButton("Get Quotes..");
        buttonConstrsint.add(getQuotesButton);
        gui.add(buttonConstrsint, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        getQuotesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                        "Last Name",
                        "Sport",
                        "# of Years",
                        "Vegetarian"};


                Object[][] data = {
                        {"Kathy", "Smith",
                         "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
                        {"John", "Doe",
                         "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
                        {"Sue", "Black",
                         "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
                        {"Jane", "White",
                         "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
                        {"Joe", "Brown",
                         "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
                    };




                JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);


                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
                table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);



                gui.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                gui.revalidate();
                gui.repaint();
            }
        });

        JOptionPane jOptionPane = new JOptionPane(gui);

        JDialog dialog = jOptionPane.createDialog(new JFrame(), "title");
        dialog.setSize(200, 200);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: That was good, though still I don't see scroll bar on the table. your test shows scroll bar but not on mine, could be becos i add table guicenter and guicenter to gui pane?